# how to positioning on bootstrap correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place the button correctly where I drew it in red, but I'm a little confused.

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP8Ex.png)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col mt-3 text-center">
                <h1 class="hellotext text-light">Hey, <span class="usertext">how was your day?</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-cry btn-xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-bad btn-xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-normal btn-xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-good btn-xl"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-verygood btn-xl"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-2">
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <textarea class="form-control w-50" cols="10" rows="7"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <div class="btn submitbtn">Submit</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I try change col, row and css, but I couldn't do what I wanted. If I give 200px margin to submitbtn, I can solve the problem, but is this the right way? I would also appreciate it if you can tell me the mistakes I made in the code.

Comment: Please include a [mre] including your CSS.

Comment: Replace justify-content-center with justify-content-start class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving your text area a width of 50% you can give that width to the outer row to make all elements have a width of 50%. That way you can replace the `justify-content-center` class from the div wrapping around your button.
See the code below:

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row text-center w-50">
        <div class="col mt-3 text-center">
            <h1 class="hellotext text-light">Hey, <span class="usertext">how was your day?</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-cry btn-xl"></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-bad btn-xl"></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-normal btn-xl"></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-good btn-xl"></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-verygood btn-xl"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-2">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="10" rows="7"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start">
                    <div class="btn submitbtn">Submit</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```